# Display image from Webform submission using views

Tags: webforms

I have created webform with title, description and upload file fields. And I have created views to display submission data in a grid view.

For images, it just giving me the image name with URL to image but it is not displaying as an image. I tried everything, but didn't find any solution. Please give me solution for displaying images in views.

Comment: "I tried everything, but didn't find any solution." Why don't you tell us what you tried?

Comment: @cilefen - 1. Google it. 2. Rewrite the output with image tag but the output is coming as a href tag, so i can't rewrite output. 3. calling the hook function to alter the field data but failed 4. Finally tried to create a template file for this field, but don't know how to alter in that, getting a big array of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**This can not be done with webform module alone.**
All you need to do is get help of 2 extra modules.

1. [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)
2. [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view)

Further you need to do following things.

1. Download and enable both of the modules and clear the cache.
2. Webform is storing file, not only image. I am assuming here you are only uploading image files, you can further get idea to show any type of file there. So go to Image File Type Display: `admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display` and set the preview/image style. Or if you do not want to change settings for default view mode of the file, download another module [Entity View Mode](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode). Go to it's configuration and create specific display and set image style accordingly in file display settings.
3. Create a view of files, it should be a block. and there add contextual filter for the fid and add field "`File: Rendered`". You can set file view mode by this field. For your convenience I'm exporting the view below, you just need to import this.

```
    $view = new view();
    $view->name = 'file_view';
    $view->description = '';
    $view->tag = 'default';
    $view->base_table = 'file_managed';
    $view->human_name = 'File view';
    $view->core = 7;
    $view->api_version = '3.0';
    $view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

    /* Display: Master */
    $handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
    $handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'File view';
    $handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
    $handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
    $handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
    $handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
    $handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
    $handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'some';
    $handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '5';
    $handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
    $handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
    /* Field: File: Name */
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['id'] = 'filename';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['field'] = 'filename';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['label'] = '';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['filename']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
    /* Field: File: Rendered */
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['id'] = 'rendered';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['field'] = 'rendered';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['label'] = '';
    $handler->display->display_options['fields']['rendered']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
    /* Contextual filter: File: File ID */
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['id'] = 'fid';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['table'] = 'file_managed';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['field'] = 'fid';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['default_action'] = 'default';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['default_argument_type'] = 'node';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
    $handler->display->display_options['arguments']['fid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';

    /* Display: Single File View */
    $handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Single File View', 'block');
```

4. Now in your main view (where you are showing submissions). Add a new relationship for `Webform submissions: Data`. You'll need to set the nid for the webform here and select the image component.
5. Add new field to the view `submission data: Value (raw)`. This will give you the file_id for the associated file. Exclude it from display.
6. Add another field `Global: View`. Select the view you imported and the block display. In contextual filter set [!data] from replacement patterns. It was the raw value of the field which you excluded from the display. And Here you go, save the view and rock :). Thanks for asking such good question. Still if you face any problem during this tutorial, ask me.

Comment: Thank you for your nice tutorial. Let me try and get back to you...once again thank you:)

Comment: :) welcome brother

Comment: Hi Himanshu - Its working perfectly. Thank you so much Genius...:)

Comment: Looking for some more good questions :)

Comment: created custom view mode too ?

Comment: yes, i have set in File View i have set custom view to File rendered but is it really needed?

Comment: Not really but preferred. If you want to show file in other views also then only default view mode will be rendered, if you want to have different image style for that view, then you need to be specific about the view mode. Otherwise default is ok

Comment: How to apply image styles to the images, as it is displaying original image in bigger size in the ajax calls?

Comment: go to admin/structure/file-types/manage/image/file-display and make sure image is checked.. you'll see image style at bottom

Comment: I used [Webform Multiple File module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_multiple_file), then every file uploaded in that component will be a separate row in the final view. I'd like all files uploaded in that component by a certain user would be merged into a single view, which means the file_view could contain all the files in the multiple_file component of every single submission. I tried, but failed:-(

Comment: hello @fishfree I haven't tried your scenario.. have you found some way or need help ?

Comment: I have to enable "Distinct" in the view advanced settings section. But this is not an elegant solution. Because I want to apply colorbox effect on the images, every single image still has its own separated effect other than an expected continuous colorbox effect.

Comment: can you export your view and give me http://pastebin.com URL ?